# Discriminating for early detection of problems

Tags: time-series

I could (please) use some suggestions on how to tackle an issue that has been brought up where I work.

When a new product is launched, our company tracks how many AND what type of replacement parts are used for products where we need to honor the warranty associated with the product.

The data are aggregated at the weekly level, and thus, could be considered a time series.

Some questions management is wondering include:

1. How to tell if any of a product's parts are being replaced at an excessively high rate for the purposes of catching that particular lot before more of it goes out the door to distributors, etc.
2. How to tell if the general trend of the rate of replacement may be changing over time.

Management has not told me what they consider an "excessively high rate", so I am wondering what might be a plausible way to go about drawing that line in the sand.

This question is intended to be more of a brainstorming kind of question.

Thanks in advance to any and all who answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

### Data:

- Are certain replacement parts more expensive? Would it make more sense to sum the cost of the replacement parts rather than the quantity?
- Are certain products more popular? That is, would it make more sense to consider the total parts replaced or maybe the number of parts replaced divided by how many parts that product has sold?
- Are certain products similar? Is there a useful category that certain products can be bucketed into?

### Analysis

Assuming that the bottom line is the total number of parts replaced, initially the data on which type of replacement part can be disregarded (and perhaps looked into after a problem is identified).  This problem can be set up as a regression problem where

- y = sum of parts replaced per week per product
- x1 = week
- x2 = product

Aad the regression formula is

y = x1 + x2 + x1 * x2

From this, we can infer whether a product has a higher than average number of replacement parts by looking at the coefficient for x2. If it is positive and large, that means something may be up.

The overall trend of replacement parts is represented by the coefficient for x1.  If this is positive and large, then *all* products have an increasing trend in replacement parts.

The specific trend for each product--apart from the overall trend--would be the coefficient for x1 * x2.  If this is positive, then the product identified by x2 is increasing in replacement parts.